# Why isn't my login function displaying the desired result?

Tags: c++, c, printf

I need to create a simple login function that verifies if a certain user is found in a .txt file. I need to use a parent, child and grandchild process. However, when I run the program, I don't get the result I want. I suppose either buff or mesaj_log don't change. For some reason, the execution seems to stop after the printf("Dati un nume de utilizator"); line and I don't really understand why. I'll leave the code here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    char buff[256] = " ";
    while (strcmp(buff, "am iesit\n"))
    {
        int pfd1[2], pfd2[2];
        int pid;
        char comanda[64];
        if (pipe(pfd1) < 0) // creez un pipe
        {
            printf("Eroare la crearea pipe-ului");
            exit(1);
        }

        if (pipe(pfd2) < 0) // creez un pipe
        {
            printf("Eroare la crearea pipe-ului");
            exit(1);
        }
        pid = fork();
        if (pid) //parinte
        {
            printf("dati o comanda>>");
            scanf("%s", comanda);
            close(pfd1[0]); //inchid capatul de citire pt primul pipe-> procesul fiu va scrie in pipe;
            close(pfd2[1]); //inchid capatul de scriere pt al doilea pipe
            write(pfd1[1], comanda, 256);
            read(pfd2[0], buff, 256);
            printf("%s", buff);
            close(pfd1[1]); // inchid si capatul de pipe utilizat (capatul de scriere)
            close(pfd2[0]);
        }
        if (pid == 0) //sunt in copil
        {
            close(pfd1[1]); //inchid capatul de scriere al pipe-ului
            close(pfd2[0]); //inchid capatul de citire al celui de-al doilea pipe
            read(pfd1[0], comanda, 256);
            if (strcmp(comanda, "Login:username") == 0)
            {
                int pfd3[2];
                int pid2;
                char mesaj_log[256]=" ";
                if (pipe(pfd3) < 0) // creez un pipe
                {
                    printf("Eroare la crearea pipe-ului");
                    exit(1);
                }
                if ((pid2 = fork()) == -1)
                {
                    printf("eroare la fork");
                }
                if (pid2 == 0) //sunt in primul nepot
                {
                    close(pfd3[0]); //inchid capatul de citire
                    char nume[256]=" ";
                    memset(nume, 0, sizeof(nume));
                    printf("dati un nume de utilizator: ");
                    scanf("%s", nume);
                    printf("aici");
                    FILE *in_file = fopen("utilizatori.txt", "r");
                    char *string;
                    memset(string, 0, sizeof(string));
                    int ok1 = 0;
                    while (!feof(in_file))
                    {
                        fscanf(in_file, "%s", string);
                        if (strcmp(nume, string) == 0)
                        {
                            ok1 = 1;
                            strcpy(mesaj_log, "conectat\n");
                            write(pfd3[1], mesaj_log, 256);
                        }
                    }
                    if (ok1 == 0)
                    {
                        strcpy(mesaj_log, "Utilizator inexistent\n");
                        write(pfd3[1], mesaj_log, 256);
                    }
                    printf("%s", mesaj_log);
                    close(pfd3[1]); //inchid capatul de citire
                    exit(0);
                }
                else if (pid2)
                {
                    close(pfd3[1]); //inchid capat de scriere
                    read(pfd3[0], &mesaj_log, 256);
                    strcpy(buff, mesaj_log);
                    write(pfd2[1], buff, 256);
                    close(pfd3[0]);
                    close(pfd1[0]);
                    exit(0);
                }
            }
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

I appreciate any feedback/answers!

Comment: This is a perfect opportunity to use a debugger to see why it stops where you say. Start by putting a breakpoint on that line. Then single step after the breakpoint is hit.

Comment: @drescherjm I'm still a noob at using gdb and it confuses me. Could the problem be with scanf?

Answer (score 0):

This may not fully cover the question but worth a try

```
char *string;
memset(string, 0, sizeof(string));

fscanf(in_file, "%s", string);
```

The above causes the problem , you declared a pointer and using it without a valid memory address, you should allocate memory first.

```
char *string = NULL;
string = malloc(STRSIZE);// use STRSIZE sufficient for storing the string.
if(string)
{
    ...
```